# Prove that there are infinitely many primes of form $2kp+1$ where $p$ is an odd prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that there are infinitely many primes of  form $2kp+1$ where $p$ is an odd prime

---

Suppose there are only finitely many primes of form $2kp+1$ :  $$p_1,p_2,\cdots, p_r$$

I am trying to mimic euclid's infinte prime proof. But not getting a suitable number to consider. Any help ?

Comment: What type of numbers has only prime factors of the form $2kp+1$?

Comment: I know odd prime factors of $2^p-1$ are of form $2kp+1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^{p-1}$. let $n=2p_1p_2\cdots p_r$. Then $f(n)$ must have a prime factor, $q$. Show that $q\equiv 1\pmod p$. Show that $q\neq p_i$ for any $i$.

---

**Details:** Since $f(x)(x-1)=x^p-1,$ if $q\mid f(n)$ then $q\mid n^p-1$ and thus $n^p\equiv 1\pmod q.$

Since $q\neq p_i$ for any $i,$ we know that the multiplicative order of $n$ modulo $q$ is $p,$ and hence $p\mid q-1,$ so $q\equiv 1\pmod p.$

Of course, $q-1$ is also even, since $q$ is odd, so we get $q=2pk+1$ for some $k.$

Comment: Thanks you :) how is this different from considering the number $N = 2p_1p_2\cdots p_r + 1$ ? I see both numbers leave a remainder $1$ when divided by $p_i$; So I think $q \equiv 1 \pmod p$ follows immediately

Comment: It is not true for your $N$ that any factor $q$ has $q\equiv 1\pmod p$. The above essentially makes sure that is true.

Comment: Just because $N\equiv 1\pmod {p_i}$ doesn't mean that if $q\mid N$ then $q\equiv 1\pmod p$. For example, if $r=1$, $p=5$ and $p_1=11$ then $2\cdot 11+1=23$ and so the only $q$ is $q=23$ and $23\not\equiv 1\pmod 5$.