# Infinite primes of the form $2kp+1$, $p$ is an odd prime and $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How do I prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $2kp+1$ such that $p$ is an odd prime and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. The hint in the book I am using suggests considering the number $(2q_1q_2\cdots q_r)^p-1$

I assumed a finite number of primes of the form $2k+1,$ namely $q_1,q_2,\cdots q_r$. We can see that the number $n={\underbrace{(2q_1q_2\cdots q_r)}_Q}^p-1\equiv1(\mod p)$.

Hence, $n$ is of the form $2kp+1$ such that $q_1,q_2\cdots q_r\nmid n$. $n$ can be factorized as $(Q-1)(1+Q+Q^2+Q^3\cdots+Q^{p-1})$. Now, both $(Q-1), (1+Q+Q^2+\cdots Q^{p-1})$ are of the form $2kp+1$. But how do I prove that one of them is either prime or has a new factor of the form $2kp+1$.

A similar question is asked here:
[Prove that there are infinitely many primes of form 2kp+1
where p is an odd prime.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927959/prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-primes-of-form-2kp1-where-p-is-an-odd) 
I could not find any useful solution out of it since it was too short.

Comment: All prime factors of $$\frac{Q^p-1}{Q-1}$$ are of the form $2kp+1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer How? I might be missing something very elementary here so please feel free to point out. My understanding is this $\frac{Q^p-1}{Q-1}=1+Q+Q^2\cdots Q^{p-1}\equiv1(\mod p)$. 
Here's why I am getting a little confused? Could there be two factors of the above expression of the form $2kp-1$ so that eventually the remainder is $1\mod p$. Please comment.

Comment: Let $r$ be a prime factor of $\frac{Q^p-1}{Q-1}$. What is the order of $Q$ modulo $r$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I guess $p$ Since $r\mid 1+Q+Q^2\cdots Q^{p-1},\therefore Q(1+Q+Q^2\cdots Q^{p-2})\equiv -1(\mod r)\implies Q(1+Q+Q^2\cdots+Q^{p-1})-Q^p\equiv -1\mod r$.

Comment: Yes, the order is $p$. Since $Q^p \equiv 1 \pmod{r}$ it can only be either $1$ or $p$. Thus it remains to see that it isn't $1$, i.e. $Q \not\equiv 1 \pmod{r}$. Now $\gcd\bigl(Q-1,\frac{Q^p-1}{Q-1}\bigr) = \gcd(Q-1,p)$, and I've overlooked that you don't have $p$ in the list of factors of $Q$, so it might just happen that $p$ also divides $\frac{Q^p-1}{Q-1}$. Well. Then one would have to show that that's not a power of $p$. It's simpler to add $p$ to the factors of $Q$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think $1+Q+Q^2\cdots Q^{p-1}(\mod p)\equiv (1+2+2^2\cdots 2^{p-1})(\mod p)\equiv (2^p-1)\mod p\equiv 1\mod p$. Therefore, p cannot divide $\frac{Q^p-1}{Q-1}$. Right? Moreover, $p\nmid Q$

Comment: Ah, right, $Q \equiv 2\pmod{p}$. That saves it indeed.

Comment: https://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/MerDiv.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the arithmetic progressions

$$1,2p+1,2(2p)+1,3(2p)+1,\cdots$$

Since $1$ is relatively prime to $2p$, by [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) we know this sequence has infinitely many prime numbers in it.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention I used Drichlett to solve it. But I am looking for a proof along the lines of what I have outlined in the question.